# How to enable IO.ANSI in elixir

Tags: elixir, ascii

I want to be able to print in color in [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir), and I read that the way is with [`IO.ANSI`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/IO.ANSI.html?), but it doesn't work.

If I do `IO.ANSI.enabled?()` I get false, so how do I get it to return true & print in color.

Answer (score 0):

`IO.ANSI.enabled?` is a helper function that is going to return the value of the `:ansi_enabled` environment setting in the `:elixir` application. The [hex docs](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/IO.ANSI.html#enabled?/0) link directly to the source code so you can see how the function is [implemented](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.10.4/lib/elixir/lib/io/ansi.ex#L42).

If you start `IEx` in a terminal you should see `IO.ANSI.enabled?` return true, or try `elixir -e 'IO.puts IO.ANSI.enabled?'`. The same hex docs I link above mention that it will be set to true when Elixir detects at start up that both stdout and stderr are connected to a terminal.

If you want to send ANSI color codes somewhere other than a terminal, you can flip the value of `:ansi_enabled` like this:

```
Application.put_env(:elixir, :ansi_enabled, true)
```

Comment: Although that will update the value of the configuration setting, it won't make a user's terminal support ANSI codes. I mention that just in case the OP's shell just doesn't support ANSI for whatever reason.